# Does issuing new bonds tend to raise yields empirically?

Tags: economic-growth, bonds, long-run, yield

Suppose a national government issues new long dated bonds (say 30y) to finance capital investment which leads to higher long term growth. For convenience purposes lets assume everything here is zero coupon. Issuing them raises the supply of bonds expiring in 30 years, which should reduce their price and lead to higher yields.

However equally the higher economic growth caused by returns on investment will make it easier for the government to successfully pay off the bond when it matures, thus decreasing the risk of a default, as well as result in more goods being produced by the economy compared to the counterfactual world where no bonds were issued, thus having a deflationary effect. Both of these lead to investors accepting lower yields when they come to buy the bond.

I'd like to ask which of these two effects generally dominates empirically when a country issues new bonds. I tried to search on Google etc. but couldn't find much useful information.